# How to use the for loop to find the sum of a geometric series

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and I tried to find a command for finding the sum of a geometric series. I tried to use the `for` loop and came up with this:

```
x=0
for(i in 1:1000){
x = x + 3 * 0.5^(i-1)
return(x)
}
```

But it returns x = 3. I can't seem to know where is the problem? Also while looking over the internet, I came across this

```
geomsum = function(a, r, n) {
x = 0

for(i in 1:n) x = x + a * r^(i-1)
return(x)
}
```

and this works even though it's very similar to my code. If someone could tell me what am I missing?

Comment: The two are not similar. Look at your `}` bracket. In your case, `return(x)` is inside the for loop, while in the case you tried to look at, they do not use `{}` hence meaning that the `return(x)` statement is OUTSIDE the for loop. IE Run only AFTER the for-loop has finished running

Comment: Also no need of for loop. you could do `geomsum1 <- function(a, r, n) a * sum(r^seq(0, n-1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `return(x)` is weird in this case: it breaks out of the loop on the first iteration. Try just

```
x=0
for(i in 1:1000) {
   x = x + 3 * 0.5^(i-1)
}
```

Then `print(x)` to see the value of `x`.

In the `geomsum` case you cite above, (1) this is an actual function, so `return(...)` make sense; (2) the body of the loop is a single statement (`x = x + a * r^(i-1)`), so the `return(...)` comes *after* the loop finishes.  The problem with code that looks like this:

```
x=0
for(i in 1:1000) {
   x = x + 3 * 0.5^(i-1)
}
return(x)
```

is that it gives an error ("no function to return from, jumping to top level"). But you don't really need the `return(x)` anyway, since you're not working inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
i=1:1000
sum(3 * 0.5^(i-1))
```